# Yii Route All Actions To One Method In Controller

Tags: php, routes, yii

I'm trying to make a cms like app using Yii. The functionality is going to be something like:

http://www.example.com/article/some-article-name

What I am trying to do is have everything go the method `actionIndex()` in the `ArticleController.php`, and have that one method determine how to handle the action. So my question is how can I route all actions to one method in a controller in Yii?

Comment: `catchAllRequest` param in config file. Set it to any method you want.

Comment: But I only want it this controller, and this catchAllRequest docs seems to be a site wide param

Comment: there might be a way to do this, but i need to know what you mean by "handle the action", and how you plan to determine?

Comment: Handle the action...where I get the action through Yii with something  like Yii::app()-> controller -> action (or some method like it) and determine a view based on that.

Comment: looks like a good candidate for using beforeAction or filter, check answer

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think it'll be better to use either a [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) or a [`beforeAction` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail).

---

Filter way:

> Filter is a piece of code that is configured to be executed before and/or after a controller action executes.

Sample:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    // ... other code ...

    public function filters() {
        return array(
            // .. other filters ...
            'mysimple', // our filter will be applied to all actions in this controller
            // ... other filters ...
        );
    }

    public function filterMysimple($filterChain) { // this is the filter code
        // ... do stuff ...
        $filterChain->run(); // this bit is important to let the action run
    }

    // ... other code ...
}
```

---

`beforeAction` way:

> This method is invoked right before an action is to be executed (after all possible filters.) You may override this method to do last-minute preparation for the action.

Sample:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    // ... other code ...

    protected function beforeAction($action) {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)){

            // do stuff

            return true; // this line is important to let the action continue
        }
        return false;
}

    // ... other code ...
}
```

---

As a side note, you can access the current action within a controller this way also : `$this->action` , to get the value of `id`: `$this->action->id`:

```
if($this->action->id == 'view') { // say you want to detect actionView
    $this->layout = 'path/to/layout'; // say you want to set a different layout for actionView 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the beginning of urlManager rules in the config:

```
'article/*' => 'article',
```

Comment: No, doesn't do it. -  'rules'=>array(
    'articles/*'=>'articles',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<cid:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),

Comment: Not `articles`, but `article`. You have an `ArticleController`, right?

Comment: Article was just an easy identifiable example, the real controller is Documents and its the same result.

Comment: Tested on my local and it works. All routes like `article/foo`, `article/bar` goes to the `ArticleController::actionIndex`... Not sure what's going on on your side, does it give you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules will have to be similar to the following :-

```
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'article/index',
        ),
```

This will pass all requests to the `actionIndex` function in the `ArticleController`PHP Class if the Controller and/or Action does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just wanna throw in a bunch of static pages in your "view" folder and have them selected and rendered automatically without adding an action for each of them in your controller.

The above suggested filters() and beforeAction() and even __construct() do not work for this purpose (filters and beforeaction do not fire up at all if the action does not exist, and __construct is very messy because if you put your functionality in __construct - at that point Yii doesnt even know which controller/action/view it should call)

however, there is a simple workaround which involves URL manager

in your config, in URL manager's rules, add one of the following lines (depending on your path settings)

```
'articles/<action:\w+>' => 'articles/index/action/<action>',
```

OR

```
'articles/<action:\w+>' => 'articles/index?action=<action>',
```

and then, in your articles controller just put up this (or similar) index action

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $name = Yii::app()->request->getParam('action');
    $this->render($name);
}
```

then you can call pages like /articles/myarticle or /articles/yourarticle without putting up any function in your controller. All you would need to do is just add a file named myarticle.php or yourarticle.php in your views/articles folder, and type your html content inside those files.